# Find the Mobius transformation of the disc $\{z:|z+1|\leq 1\}$ onto the complement of the disc $\{z:|z+2|<1\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the Mobius transformation of the disc $\{z:|z+1|\leq 1\}$ onto the complement of the disc $\{z:|z+2|<1\}$? How to find the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation $z\mapsto z+1$ sends the disc $\{z:|z+1|\leq 1\}$ to the disc $\{|z|\leq 1\}$, then the transformation $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ sends this disc to $\{z:|z|\geq 1\}$, and finally the map $z\mapsto z-2$ sends $\{z:|z|\geq 1\}$ to $\{z:|z+2|\geq 1\}$. So the desired Mobius transformation is the composition of these three maps.

Comment: If I am correct this is not the only solution this solution maps the center of the disc to   infinity  while you can map any point inside the disk to infinity

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are many solutions. Perhaps my use of "the" in my last sentence gave the wrong impression.